# Imputation of uni-variate, seasonal time series using linear model

Tags: r, imputation

How can we perform imputation on uni-variate, seasonal time series using a linear model approach in R? It should account for seasonality and, preferably, trend.
I have used [tslm](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/forecast/versions/8.4/topics/tslm) function for forecast but do not know a similar function for imputation.

Comment: imputation most frequently involves the use of at least one related variable. If you're not doing that, a smoothing approach will be your best bet.... But as noted, please provide a reproducible example. As currently written, this question is overly broad and should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The the [imputeTS](https://cran.r-project.org/package=imputeTS) package might be what you are searching.
(disclaimer: I am maintainer of the package)

It is a package especially for (univariate) time series imputation.
This means it also has functions able to handle seasonality and trend.

There are actually several functions in the package that could be of interest for you:

- na_seadec - uses loess decomposition and interpolation
- na_kalman - uses kalman smoothing & structural time series models
- na_seasplit - imputes for each season separately

There are also other algorithms included, but these three seem most promising for your needs. I would suggest reading the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeTS/imputeTS.pdf) for concrete algorithm details.

Short example for you:

```
library(imputeTS)
# tsAirgap is a example univariate time series with NAs provided by imputeTS 
x <- tsAirgap
x <- na_kalman(x)
```

That's it basically. For the other algortihms it would work the same:

```
library(imputeTS)
# tsAirgap is a example univariate time series with NAs provided by imputeTS 
x <- tsAirgap
x <- na_seadec(x, algorithm = "interpolation")
```

Answer (score 1):

This question seems more statistical in nature so should probably be migrated to [cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) where you may get better answers...but a quick answer is that

- imputation is a distinct process from linear modeling, often performed in advance, so a bit unclear what you're asking here
- if i understand correctly, the easiest approach would probably be to use the mean value from a reasonable window of neighboring points, before fitting your tslm model
- you may want to check out the [pre-processing](http://topepo.github.io/caret/preprocess.html#impute) options available in the Caret package, though I haven't used them myself with time-series data and am not sure if it's possible

As always, providing data and a reproducible example would help here.

Comment: Thanks JohnSG. I first asked it in cross-validated but were advised it is not suitable there as it is about code not statistical advice. I need a function in r that fits a linear model to a time series with seasonality and some missing values and uses this linear model to impute the missing values. Your second bullet point gave me the clue: I can fit a linear model (lm function in r) to every vector containing the sequence of the 'n'th values of every season and use the fitted model to then calculate the missing values in that vector. And, repeat this for all 'n's (n:1,...,frequency).

Comment: Thanks also for your last comment. I will add the code with a reproducible example here when done with it so others can comment if I am wrong.

Comment: @Hapalop if you have seasonality, the above comment's approach will not work appropriately